# MS Project cost

Tags: ms-project

I'm facing a very weird behavior of MS Project when computing the project cost. Once removing subtasks from my original project I realized that changes to **some** subtasks are not reflected in the corresponding summary task. I would like to precise the following points:

1. All tasks entered in the project have a default task mode of Automatically Scheduled
2. I forced a new baseline after having removed tasks
3. I clicked on the Calculate Project button

I don't really understand why this problem occurs with some subtasks, only. I would like to know if someone experienced the same problem.
By the way I found a workaround, but I didn't fully checked my planning (more than 2000 tasks). I realized that forcing the option "Calculate project after each edit" to "On" in Project Options>Schedule>Calculation seems to fix the issue. Once more it's not clear the reason. Implementing actions (1) through (3) should be enough to recompute all summary costs. Any idea?